# Pthreads and not shared variables

Tags: c, pthreads

While following this tutorial:
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/linux-network-programming
I found very interesting behavior, please check the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>    

void *func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}

int main()
{    
    pthread_t handle;
    int exitcode;
    int i = 0;
    int y = 5;
    while (1) {
        y++;
        // i++;
        printf("primary thread: y == %d\n", y);
        pthread_create(&handle, NULL, func, "hi!");
        pthread_join(handle, (void **)&exitcode);
        sleep(1);
    }    
}

//gcc -o t failtesting.c -O0  -l pthread  ; ./t
//primary thread: y == 6
//primary thread: y == 1
//primary thread: y == 1
//^C
```

somehow joining the child thread resets variable y to 0, why does it happen?

The weirdest part is: if you uncomment i++,  everything goes back to normal:

```
gcc -o t failtesting.c -O0  -l pthread  ; ./t 
primary thread: y == 5
primary thread: y == 6
primary thread: y == 7
primary thread: y == 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ...

> ```
>     int exitcode;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>         pthread_join(handle, (void **)&exitcode);
> ```

... produces undefined behavior because the referrent of `&exitcode` is an `int`, but `pthread_join` will cause a value to be written to it as if it were a `void *`.

That's entirely sufficient in itself for the behavior to be undefined, regardless of any other consideration.  However, in thinking about *why* C might declare such situations to be UB, do consider that it is quite common for the size of a `void *` to be larger than the size of an `int`, so what's supposed to happen when the program tries to write data into a space too small for it?

> The weirdest part is: if you uncomment i++, everything goes back to normal

Anomalies such as that are a telltale sign that your program is exhibiting UB.  The C standard expressly denies there being any explanation for it -- that's part of what "undefined behavior" means.

In any case, it looks like you want this, instead:

```
    void *exit_ptr;
    pthread_join(handle, &exit_ptr);
    exitcode = (int) exit_ptr;
```

Be prepared for the compiler to emit a well-justified warning about the pointer-to-int cast, though you should be able to silence that by casting to `intptr_t`, instead.

Comment: Yeah - that '(void **)' cast was a big giveaway for the UB:)